# How can I correctly display text in Tex format?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ipython, sympy, tex, jupyterhub

I am trying to display python sympy expression in the Jupyterhub Notebook in the VS Code.
When I do it in the Google Colab, it looks fine, but in the VS Code it remains in Tex format

[image: in VS Code and Google Colab]

I tried to use init_printing from sympy but it does not help

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty simple: in VS Code you should add '$' to string in Tex format manually:

[image: solution]